# pySpark not able to handle Multiline string in CSV file while selecting columns

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to load csv file which looks like following, using pyspark code.

```
A^B^C^D^E^F
"Yash"^"12"^""^"this is first record"^"nice"^"12"
"jay"^"13"^""^"
In second record, I am new line at the beingnning"^"nice"^"12"
"Nova"^"14"^""^"this is third record"^"nice"^"12"
```

When I read this file and select a few columns entire dataframe gets messed up.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = (
    spark.read
    .option("delimiter", "^")
    .option('header',True) \
    .option("multiline", "true")
    .option('multiLine', True) \
    .option("escape", "\"")
    .csv(
        "test3.csv",
        header=True,
    )
)
df.show()
df = df.withColumn("isdeleted", F.lit(True))
select_cols = ['isdeleted','B','D','E','F']
df = df.select(*select_cols)
df.show()
```

*(truncated some import statements for readability of code)*

This is what I see when the above code runs

```
Before column selection (entire DF)
+----+---+----+--------------------+----+---+
|   A|  B|   C|                   D|   E|  F|
+----+---+----+--------------------+----+---+
|Yash| 12|null|this is first record|nice| 12|
| jay| 13|null|\nIn second recor...|nice| 12|
|Nova| 14|null|this is third record|nice| 12|
+----+---+----+--------------------+----+---+


After df.select(*select_cols)
+---------+----+--------------------+----+----+
|isdeleted|   B|                   D|   E|   F|
+---------+----+--------------------+----+----+
|     true|  12|this is first record|nice|  12|
|     true|  13|                null|null|null|
|     true|nice|                null|null|null|
|     true|  14|this is third record|nice|  12|
+---------+----+--------------------+----+----+
```

Here, second row with newline char is being broken down to 2 rows, output file is also messed up just like dataframe preview I showed above.

I am using apache Glue image amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01 which uses spark 3.3.0 version. Also tried with spark 3.1.1. I see the same issue in both versions.

I am not sure whether this is a bug in spark package or I am missing something here. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Does not happen with me, I used the same code provided in that question, works fine. I am using spark 3.3.0

Comment: @TusharPatil Can you please verify that one more time for me?
There are 2 df.show() statements don't get confused, the first one will show the correct order of columns. Second one is where it is messed up

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the wrong escape charactor. It is usually `\` and you are specifing this to the quote. Once you change the option,

```
df = spark.read.csv('test.csv', sep='^', header=True, multiLine=True)
df.show()

df.select('B').show()

+----+---+----+--------------------+----+---+
|   A|  B|   C|                   D|   E|  F|
+----+---+----+--------------------+----+---+
|Yash| 12|null|this is first record|nice| 12|
| jay| 13|null|\nIn second recor...|nice| 12|
|Nova| 14|null|this is third record|nice| 12|
+----+---+----+--------------------+----+---+

+---+
|  B|
+---+
| 12|
| 13|
| 14|
+---+
```

You will get the desired result.

Comment: This works but this way I am loosing quotes in output when I write the dataframe as csv

Comment: then add a write option `quoteAll`.